# Proper way to render integer array as a string with commas in JSX

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to render something like this: ["1", "2","3"]
as`1,2,3,4,5` in React?

```
render(){
  <p>{this.numberResult()} </p> 
}
```

this.numerResult returns `["1", "2","3"]` which ends up looking like: `123` in the browser but I would like it to return 1,2,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

**Sample Example:**

```js
const joined = ["1", "2","3"].join(",")
console.log(joined);
```

```js
render(){
  <p>{this.numberResult().join(",")} </p> 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show numbers comma separeted, use join:

```
render(){
  <p>{(this.numberResult() || []).join(', ')} </p> 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render(){
  <p>{this.numberResult().join(", ")</p> 
}
```